# Android application chrashes after "share" intent

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-intent, share

My app offers a **"share/tell-a-friend"** function. When the "share" button is pressed the following method is being called to open a list of apps, which can perform the action (Eg. Gmail, Twittroid, Facebook...):

```
public void share() {
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getText(R.string.menu_share_subject));
    shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getText(R.string.menu_share_body));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getText(R.string.menu_share_intent)));      
}
```

The sharing functionality works basically. But when the sharing app (Facebook, Twitter, ...) tries to return to my app, a force close is thrown.

I guess that my app gets closed in the background during the sharing process. At least that is what the debugger says.

Any ideas?

---

The problem seems to be that the app closes in the background. Also when I open the browser from my app an try to return to my app with the back key. A force close is thrown. This is the Log Cat output

```
04-13 22:28:42.003: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eu.xxx.xxx/eu.xxx.xxx.xxx}: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2401) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:116) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at eu.xxx.xxx.xxx.fillData(xxx.java:178) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at eu.xxx.xxx.xxx.access$1(xxx.java:173) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at eu.xxx.xxx.xxx$1.onTextChanged(xxx.java:139) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6096) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2677) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2542) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:71) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2517) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:2417) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:5689) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1125) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1125) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:1125) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:5668) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1506) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:833) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ListActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(ListActivity.java:221) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:805) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1172) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2378) 04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the relevant debug output

Comment: ...by which jqpublic means the Java stack trace associated with your "force close" dialog. You can get this stack trace via `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-13 22:28:42.253: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(18915): at xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.fillData(xxx.java:178)
```

You have a `NullPointerException`. Fix that, and with luck, your problems will go away.

Comment: Is there a generic way to fix that?

Comment: Yes -- don't try calling methods on a variable or data member that is `null`. If you are new to Java, I really recommend spending some time getting comfortable with the language outside of Android. Android is just strange enough that trying to learn both Java and Android at once may be confusing.

Comment: It was a problem with the lifecycle management. The variable existed in the internal app lifecycle but not when returning from another application.

Your hint and the Android developer ressources helped me to solve the problem, so thanks to both of you ;)

Helpful articles:
http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Answer (score 0):

```
public void share() {
   Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
   shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, new String(getText(R.string.menu_share_subject)));
   shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String(getText(R.string.menu_share_body)));

   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getText(R.string.menu_share_intent)));      
  }
```

does the job :)
don't know why everywhere else it does work, but with this addition, it works as expected: )
thanks also for your replies